# JavaScript event wont fire onmouse down

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have this code for js, html and CSS:

```
window.onload = function () {
console.log("aaa");
document.getElementById("back").addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
    console.log("start");
}, false);};
```

and

```
<body>
<div id="mag-glass">
    <object data="worldLow.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
    </object>
</div>
<div id="back">
    <object data="worldLow.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
    </object>
</div>
<script src="mag-glass.js"></script>
```

and CSS:

```
  #back {position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  overflow: hidden; }
  #back object {
    width: 2000px;
    height: 2000px; }
```

the problem is that the mouse down event is not fired. Is it because the object is bigger than the div? I tried to make the event for other elements as well but nothing helped.

Comment: is there any problem if you use jquery?

Comment: did you test your code in someplace like http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: with jquery it's not working as well...

Comment: okay so apparently the problem is with the object in the div because when I deleted it  the whole programm started working... however I still dont know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

It would work i have tried this on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xtayoqmr/10/) with some in html as i didnt have mag-glass.js but your problem was with event calling so it is working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        console.log("aaa");
        $("#back").on("mousedown", function () {
            console.log("start");
        });
    });
```

Comment: Yeah this would work but since I have this svg object inside the div it somehow stops working.

Comment: can you create a fiddle with the svg object in it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for responses, I solved it with deleting object a nd substituing it with just svg itself. This way it works